# How to add custom List on a list View

Tags: android, custom-lists

I am Using a custom Array adapter to add custom list on a list view but its adding only the last item in list here is my Custom array adapter

```
public class CustomCreditsOffer extends ArrayAdapter<Credits> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
Credits items;
ArrayList<Credits> resultList;

public CustomCreditsOffer(Context context, ArrayList<Credits> credits) {
    super(context, R.layout.credit_offers_sale, credits);
    resultList=credits;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder;
    items=getItem(position);
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.credit_offers_sale,parent,false);
        holder=new Holder();
        holder.creditsTV = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.creditSaleNoOfCreditsTV);
        holder.typeTV = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.creditTypeTV);
        holder.creditsPurchaseBT = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.creditSalePurchaseBT);
        holder.creditsPurchaseBT.setText(items.amount);
        holder.creditsTV.setText(items.number);
        holder.typeTV.setText(items.title);
    }

    return convertView;
}

public class Holder {
    public TextView creditsTV;
    public TextView typeTV;
    public Button creditsPurchaseBT;

}
```

}

and here is the code how i am adding items to addpater

```
@Override
public void onSyncSuccess(String controller, String action, boolean status,
        JSONObject jsonObject) {
    PostCost post=new PostCost();
    // getting Current credits
    if (status && action.compareTo("credit") == 0) {
        try {
            Credits credit=new Credits();
            credit.yourBalance= jsonObject.getString("your_balance");
            credit.premiumAmount= jsonObject.getString("premium_amount");
            credit.isPremium=jsonObject.getString("is_premium_mem");

            creditPremiumMemberBT.setText("$"+credit.premiumAmount);
            creditsYourCredits.setText(credit.yourBalance);

            if(!isPremium.equals("0")){
                creditPremiumTV.setText("You are a premium member");
                creditPremiumMemberBT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            JSONArray adminCredit=jsonObject.getJSONArray("adminCredit");

            for(int a=0;a<adminCredit.length();a++){
                JSONObject detail=adminCredit.getJSONObject(a);
                credit.number=detail.getString("number");
                credit.amount=detail.getString("amount");
                credit.title=detail.getString("type_title");
                credit.key=detail.getString("android_key");
                credit.id=detail.getString("id");
                credit.typeId=detail.getString("type_id");
                creditList.add(credit);
            }
        } 

        catch (Exception e) {

        }
        creditAdapter=new CustomCreditsOffer(getActivity(), creditList);
        creditAvailableProductOffersLV.setAdapter(creditAdapter);
    }
    }
```

What this code does is add the last item i am getting from the response from server to the list.

Comment: what is "credit", a hashmap?

Comment: a class to store data

Comment: post your credit class

Comment: try initializing the credit in loop

Comment: how could i do this??

Comment: Post class is not used in this it was by mistake i have inserted data in Credit class and then add those Credits objects to a array list creditList and then add that array list to CustomCreditsOffer adapter and set that adapter to list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change getView method to:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder;
    items=getItem(position);
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.credit_offers_sale,parent,false);
        holder=new Holder();
        holder.creditsTV = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.creditSaleNoOfCreditsTV);
        holder.typeTV = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.creditTypeTV);


        holder.creditsPurchaseBT = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.creditSalePurchaseBT);

        convertView.setTag(holder);


    }
    else
        holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag();

     holder.creditsPurchaseBT.setText(items.amount);
     holder.creditsTV.setText(items.number);
     holder.typeTV.setText(items.title);

    return convertView;
}
```

with your code you just handle if your view is null.

Comment: according to the response from server usually its 6

Comment: Are you use my code? because if you use that you must have an error, try my code one more time, because all thing is right